# rake db:create picking up old adapter database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I experimented a few weeks ago by adding a second database to my database.yml. While everything worked, I didn't like the approach and removed all the models etc of that second DB. The primary database was postgresql and the second was sqlite3.  The db location was the absolute path to the sqlite3 db in database.yml.

Every once in a while I will dump my production db on the server and pull it into my development db. I'd do this with:

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
psql -d {database} < {output from pg_dump}
```

The first time I tried this procedure after my experiment, I got a rake error:

```
xuserAir:db xuser$ rake db:create
(in /Users/xuser/Work/v/vfw-post)
/Users/xuser/vfw/gnucash/export/vfwexport.gnucash already exists
vfw-post_test already exists
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).

Gem::LoadError: sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.
```

There is no reference anywhere in my application root to sqlite3, the database path or any of the file names or directory. `rake db` seems to be picking up the old information from someplace by I have no idea where. I may have had db/development.db set up as a symbolic like to the export.db, but that is also gone.

Also `rake db:drop` deleted the sqlite3 database that was outside the app root.

I striped everything in my database.yml file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: vfw-post_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: vfw-post_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: vfw-post_production
  username: vfw
  # password: <%= ENV['VFW-POST_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

And still get the same error.

Stuck

Rails 4.2

Comment: Can you show us your Gemfile?

Comment: @neo  I found my problem and answered my own question.  I has set a DATABASE_URL env variable and it took over.

Answer (score 0):

I found out where it was coming from.

Somewhere in my experiment with two database I set up

```
DATABASE_URL=sqlite3:/Users/xuser/vfw/gnucash/export/vfwexport.gnucash
```

I think to help when I deployed. I didn't remove that and it goes to the DATABASE_URL first.